# How to group header like grid below in extjs 3.3

Tags: extjs, datagrid, grid

How to group header like grid below in extjs:

|----A1Header----|----A2Header----|---------------B3Header----------------|

|-----A1Data------|----A2 Data------|-----B3 Data------|-----B4 Data-------|

|-----A1Data------|----A2 Data------|-----B3 Data------|-----B4 Data-------|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the grid examples for Ext 3.3 uses a plugin to group columns: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.0/examples/grid/ColumnHeaderGroup.html  Try 'view source' to see and get all of the css and js files that are used.